# How to communicate properly between child process in other network namespace and parent process?

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, ipc, linux-namespaces

I am using `Popen` from [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to spawn a new process in a network namespace. I need to exchange data between the parent process and the newly spawned child process.

Currently, I am doing this by simply parsing from `stdout`, meaning that in my child process I simply print everything I need to transmit to the parent process and then parse it from the parent. Although this approach works, it seems extremely hacky and moreover, does not support a bidirectional data exchange (child -> parent and parent -> child).

I think creating a socket to communicate between the two processes does not work in my case, since the parent process is in a different network namespace.

How can I realize IPC between two separate network namespaces?

Comment: Can you post some example code? In particular, how are you spawning the child process in a new namespace? Are you doing that in Python before calling `subprocess.Popen`, or are you doing that via something like `ip netns exec` or `nsenter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket from AF_INET family would not be able to connect unless there was routing between your namespaces, but you could use unix domain sockets (`socket.AF_UNIX`). They do not use network namespace for anything as the socket is a "file" on your file system.